# List all tables in an specific PostgreSQL database using java code

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

actually i have googled a bit and i need corresponding SELECT command to following PostgreSQL shell command :

```
\dt schemaname.*
```

i managed to get all databases with following code :

```
            Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT datname FROM pg_database");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("DB Name : " + rs.getString(1));
           //i need another while here to list tables 
           //inside the selected database
}
```

i tried following statement, but no luck :

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM "
                                + rs.getString(1)
                                + " ORDER BY table_schema,table_name");
```

this is  the error i am getting :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "template1" does not exist
  Position: 37
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at com.isiran.rayten.rg.db.bare.wrapper.PGWrap.main(PGWrap.java:64)
```

Comment: the connection string is wrong, you are pointing into `template1` database.

Comment: You are apparently using the database name as the table name in your second executeQuery()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list all tables from database you have to read table `pg_catalog.pg_tables`
But unfortunately you have to be logged-in in database. 
So in place where you wrote comments

```
//i need another while here to list tables 
//inside the selected database
```

Before loop for tables you need to log-in in this database.

Comment: and how can i do that? i know i can do it by typing connect schema in shell but not sure how to do that it java

Comment: In the same way as object @connection@ was initialized in your code, but with different database name. But you need user name and password for each database or connect to databases with superuser user (e.g. postgres).

Comment: hmm. i have already connected to that database, with jdbc connection string :-?

Comment: Yes, but you try to list tables from other databases. You can't do this from current database.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `psql -E`, it'll echo the actual queries that get run when you type commands such as `\dt`:

```
denis=# \dt public.*
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','s','')
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND n.nspname ~ '^(public)$'
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************
```

These queries can then be simplified or amended per your specific use-case.

Comment: +1 for helpful comment, but as Nicolai mentioned i have to connect to schema first, i am not sure how to do that within java since it is not a query

Answer (score 7):

Use the `DatabaseMetaData` object to query information, eg [`getTables(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
try (ResultSet tables = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" })) {
    while (tables.next()) {
        System.out.println(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
}
```

This will return *all* tables in the database, you may need to specify values for `catalog` and/or `schemaPattern` to get a more specific result.

Comment: If you follow the link to the javadoc, you can see that `schemaPattern` is the second parameter.

Comment: it is working but the problem is it cant load db names so i cant pass the name as argument

Comment: As far as I know [`getSchemas()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas()) is implemented for PostgreSQL